# Background repeating SVG has small gap between repeating tiles

Tags: css, svg

I'm creating a 'lined paper' look, using a simple horizontal line, saved as an SVG, and repeating it. All works fine apart from on my iPhone I can see small gaps between the repeating tiles. I don't understand why. All my dimensions are complete pixels.

Here's my SVG image code:

```
<svg enable-background="new 0 0 108 108" viewBox="0 0 108 108" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="m0 107h108" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1px" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/>
</svg>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
h2 {
    font-size: 11.5vw;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    background-image: url("images/lines.svg");
    background-size: 1.5em;
}
```

And here is a screen grab of the gaps

[image]

UPDATE
At smaller screen sizes the font size is actually 11.5vw. This will result in font-size of not whole pixels, and therefore the background size will not be whole pixels – and hence this might account for the gaps?

Thank you

Comment: I just tried to emulate your problem but I just can't see the gaps with the code you provided.

Comment: I've only seen the issue on a phone: the lines looked broken, and then when zooming in, you can see there are gaps between the repeating background image.

Comment: I've just updated my question. See 'update'. I've realised at smaller screen sizes my font size is set in 'vw', resulting in sub-pixel measurements. Which in turn means the background image will not whole pixels. Could this be why the background tiles have gaps?

Comment: Exactly. Always use integer px sizes for repeating patterns. Otherwise, you will run into rounding errors.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" shape-rendering="crispEdges">
   <!-- Your SVG content here -->
</svg>
```

Use shape-rendering Property:
You can try using the shape-rendering property on your SVG elements to control the way they are rendered. Setting shape-rendering="crispEdges" can help avoid anti-aliasing and potentially reduce gaps.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my solution.

On the SVG file add in `preserveAspectRatio="none"`:

```
<svg enable-background="new 0 0 108 108" viewBox="0 0 108 108" preserveAspectRatio="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="m0 107h108" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1px" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/>
</svg>
```

Then the CSS can stretch the SVG file to be 100% width of the container. While the height is still `1.5em` of the `text-size`:

```
h2 {
    font-size: 11.5vw;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    background-image: url("images/lines.svg");
    background-size: 100% 1.5em;
    background-repeat: none, repeat;
}
```

Note. the `vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"` keeps the 1px stroke-width 1px regardless of the size/scale of the SVG.